# PTC Integrity batch update member revision

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

Is there a way to update the member revision of a big list of files via command line?

I can't use `:working` or `:head` but have to specify a different revision for each file.

As far as I know `--selectionFile` only takes paths as input, but not the revision numbers.

*edit:* I wanted to set member a very big list of files and I wanted to avoid writing the command `si updaterevision ...` for every file, as it takes ages to complete for that many files. Instead I wanted to know if there is a more advanced method to specify a list of files and their revisions to be able to run the updaterevision only once (like it is with `:working`) for the whole list of files.

But as it is said in the comment there is no such possibility.

*edit2:* I use MKS for a couple of years now and as I now know, **there is no such possibility** (at least up to MKS 11.6) to update many files to different revisions with **one single** command line call. But using one call per member, as was proposed, made the whole operation take up to several hours as I had many thousands of members in the sandbox and MKS needs some time to complete each `si`command.

Comment: you need to process the list of files in a loop

Answer (score 1):

Some time already passed since you asked for this question, here is my comment in case it could still be useful for you in the future.

First, It is not completely clear what you want to achieve. Please be more descriptive and if possible provide example.

What I understand as of now is you need to set bunch of files listed as member revision thru the command line. This is fairly simple, the most complicated is actually to have the list of files to be updated to member and the revision that you want to set as member.

I recommend you to create a batch file with the commands to make each file member. You can use Regex to do it very quick and without much trouble.

Here is an example for updating one file member revision:

```
si updaterevision --hostname=servername --port=portnumber --user=username --changepackageid=5873763:2 --revision=:working myfile_a1.c
```

where

> servername = the name of the server where your sandbox is located
>
> portnumber = the port that provides access to the server for your sandbox
>
> username = your login user id
>
> changepackageid = here you change the number to use your defined TASK:ChangePackage for this changes
>
> revision = if you have a working revision that you want now to become member, just use "working" as revision, otherwise you can define specific revision number, e.g. revision=1.2
>
> At the end you define the name of the file you want to update.

Go to you sandbox root folder, open CMD window, and run the batch file. It will execute each line applying your changes.

---

If you have a list of files with the revision you want as member, you can use REGEX to convert it into a batch file.

Example list of files in text file: 

`file1.c 1.10
file3.c 1.19
sec_file1.c 1.1.2.1
support.h 1.7`

Use notepad++ or other text editor with regex support and run this search: 
[image: You can see the regex: ([\w]*.[\D]*)\s+([\d.]+).* will find 2 matches per line: 1)the file name, 2) revision,]

Once you know which regex apply, you can now use it in the notepad++ to do a simple search and replace:

> Search = ([\w]*.[\D]*)\s+([\d.]+).*
>
> Replace = si updaterevision --hostname=servername --port=portnum --user=userid --changepackageid=6123933:4 --revision=\2 \1
>
> \1 => FileName
>
> \2 => File revision

See image below as example: 
[image]

Finally just save doc as batch file and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Just speculating that if you have a large list of members along with the member revision you want to update to, then you also have an sandbox that served you to generate this list.

If so my approach would be

c:\MySandbox> si updaterevision --recurse --revision=:working

If your member/revision list come from a development path you could first have a sandbox targeting that devpath, resync, (close thesandbox if opened in gui), retarget the sandbox to the destination devpath (or mainline) you want and then issue the command above.

For an single member approach I would use 'si rlog' to generate a list of si-commands directly

```
si rlog -R --noheaderformat --notrailerformat --revision=:working --format="si updaterevision {membername} --revision={revision}\r\n" > updaterevs.bat.txt
```

Review updaterevs.bat.txt rename it to updaterevs.bat and ecxecute it.
(Be careful if using it on other sandboxes)

Other interesting readings here might be the "snapshot sandbox" feature, 
checkpointing in general and variants rsp. devpaths.
**Using only these features might be politically more correct in the philosophy of Integrity.**